# ListView yielding nullpointerexception on setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I'm attempting to work with through some tutorial code and add in an OnItemClick Listener, but keep throwing an exception when it hits the listener and crashing my app. This is my first attempt at working in the Android environment, so I'm trying to learn how all these things are interrelated.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class RssActivity extends ListActivity{

private RssListAdapter adapter;

private OnItemClickListener newsSelectListener = new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(RssActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Clicked").setMessage("Item clicked").setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();

        }
    };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<JSONObject> jobs = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    try {
        jobs = RssReader.getLatestRssFeed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
    }   

    adapter = new RssListAdapter(this,jobs);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(newsSelectListener);

    }
}
```

I also tried to changing setListAdapter to lv.setListAdapter, but that's doesn't appear to be a valid statement.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're not setting `setContentView` - look at my answer.

Comment: @Xeon - Thanks. I was actually able to access the listener without setting setContentView. Check zipc's approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListActivity doesn't require you to assign a layout via `setContentView()` that is if you want to show **only** a list but if you add a another view, your ListView should contain the `android:id` attribute set to `@android:id/list` like this xml below

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

try changing your code

`ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);`

to this

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(newsSelectListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure your code will work

```
private OnItemClickListener newsSelectListener = new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(RssActivity.this);
        alert.setTitle("Clicked").setMessage("Item clicked").setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();

    }
};
```

But in my opinion, I often add `setOnClickListener()` to convertView in `getView` method in `Adapter` class

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
......................
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Do Somethings in here
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see where you have initialized your layout...so:

> `Activity` class takes care of creating a window for you in which you
>   can place your UI with `setContentView(View)`.

The `onCreate(Bundle)` method initializes your `Activity`. It is where you usually call `setContentView(int)` with your xml layout(`main.xml` or your xml which defines your UI). Place it after `super.onCreate(..)`

---

With regards with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}:
```

check your `AndroidManifest.xml` if your `Activity` is already in there:

```
<activity android:name=".<ActivityName>" 
          android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

---

If your problem has not been resolved, make use of your `Logcat` and put `Log.d` in your methods to see where it's crashing.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Ok - and where are you setting `setContentView(...)`? The `lv`

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

is null because you didn't set contentView.

---

Probably the reason for this is: you're setting `OnClickListener` to `null` in `AlertDialog.Builder` in `setNeutralButton("OK", null)`.

So when you click "OK" Android invokes (internally) something like this:

```
neutralButtonListener.onClick(...);
```

And the `neutralButtonListener` is `null`. So you should just provide empty listener at least.

Comment: The button isn't the issue from what I can tell. The activity won't launch at all. I never get to see listview. The crash occurs during the onCreate when it hits the listener. Here's how the exception is explained: 05-31 17:28:00.527: E/AndroidRuntime(939): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...RssActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException